# What is the most lightweight container in Flex 4?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

In the root of my application I have 5 named "slots" (layers) that I want content to appear in. Should I be using Canvas, Group or something else for each of these slots? I don't need any kind of automatic layout inside these slots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Group. You can plug a custom layout into it if you wish. Here's a good preso on what's new with Flex 4 Lists and Layouts:

http://tv.adobe.com/watch/max-2009-develop/a-deep-dive-into-flex-4-lists-and-layouts/

Comment: I decided to go with Group. Was just wondering if there was a more lightweight alternative.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need any layout and scrolling, then you can use UIComponent as a container.

Comment: Will that work OK with Flex 4? IE, can I throw a Group into that UIComponent later?